# Building and running a docker image from TFS builds

Tags: tfsbuild, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I have a dockerfile which builds an ubuntu image with my latest source code and compiles it. My docker-machine is called default and runs under user xyz on a windows machine. If I am logged in as user xyz and run buildscript.bat (which sets up the shell environment and builds image, runs container etc) everything works beautifully. 
However, I want this task automated through TFS. My TFS build service runs as user xyz in headless mode and when the buildscript.bat is executed, I see this error:

Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running

So clearly, default docker-machine is not being found. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Building the Docker image from TFS XMAL build is not support. If you want deploy to the container, this can be achieved. However, you need to use the new build system vNext which means you have to upgrade TFS2013 to TFS2015.

For the deployment with docker, refer to this link for details: http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/continuous-deployment-with-docker-and-build-vnext

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I achieved my goal by running a batch script from the xaml build which executes 'docker-machine start default' followed by creating an image and running it. Clean up with 'docker-machine stop default'. It works, only downside is I need to restart docker-machine each time.